# Mock created using PHPUnit return "NULL" when class was called

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Code:

```
$mockObject = $this->getMock('ORM_User');

$mockObject->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('xxx')
    ->with($this->equalTo('a'))
    ->will($this->returnValue('aaa'));

$mockObject->expects($this->at(1))
    ->method('xxx')
    ->with($this->equalTo('b'))
    ->will($this->returnValue('bbb'));

var_dump("-".$mockObject->xxx('a'));
var_dump($mockObject->xxx('b'));  

$tmp = new ORM_User();
var_dump($tmp->xxx('a'));
var_dump($tmp->xxx('b'));
```

Output:

```
string(4) "-aaa"
string(3) "bbb"
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: In your code mock returns data, and real object returns nulls.

Comment: zerkms, there are some way to do it? thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The does to exactly what you tell it too and works fine as far as i can see it.

You create a "fake" ORM_User and tell the xxx function to return "aaa" and "bbb" and it does that.

Then you create a **real** ORM_USER and call it, that returns null but that is behond the scope of phpunit. You are just calling the real class there to i don't see where you are getting at this that.

Maybe tell us what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Additional: It seems, that you (Felipe) use `__call()` to catch all calls to undefined methods and return `null`. If not, you should think about your naming conventions for methods (`xxx()` is not a good name).

Comment: KingCrunch, the name "xxx" only was a example :D

Comment: edorian, I finally do it... Thank's